# how to avoid mass assignment error with has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes, mass-assignment

I am trying to do an update_attributes of a nested model and keep running into a mass assignment error. Here are my models:

```
class Lineup < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :piece_lineups
  has_many :pieces, through: :piece_lineups

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :piece_lineups

end

class Piece < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cost, :description, :name, :category

  has_many :piece_lineups
  has_many :lineups, through: :piece_lineups

end

class PieceLineup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :piece

  belongs_to :piece
  belongs_to :lineup

end
```

User has_one lineup by the way. So I thought that by adding accepts_nested_attributes_for to the lineup model that it would work but it is not. Here's my form:

```
  - @lineup.piece_lineups.build(:piece => piece)
  = form_for(@lineup) do |f|
    = f.fields_for :piece_lineups do |piece_lineup|
      = piece_lineup.hidden_field(:piece_id, :value => piece.id)
    = f.submit
```

and my Lineup controller action:

```
  def update
    @lineup = current_user.lineup
    @lineup.update_attributes(params[:lineup])
```

and finally, the error:

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: piece_lineups_attributes

What am i missing here? Thanks!

Comment: I think you're missing `accepts_nested_attributes_for :piece` in `PieceLineup`

Comment: this didn't work:( same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` creates an attribute writer -- in your case, `piece_lineups_attributes=` -- for passing attributes to another model. So, you need to add `attr_accessible :piece_lineups_attributes` to your Lineup model to make it mass-assignable.

**UPDATE**

There is a better way of going about this.

If you add `attr_accessible :piece_ids` to your Lineup model, then change your view to

```
= form_for(@lineup) do |f|
  = f.hidden_field(:piece_ids, :value => piece.id)
  = f.submit
```

You don't need nested attributes at all.

Comment: i tried this now I am getting a different mass assign error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: piece_id

Comment: Then add `attr_accessible :piece_id` to your PieceLinup model

Comment: great, now how do I add something that deletes that relationship?

Answer (score -1):

Mass Assignment usually means passing attributes into the call that creates an object as part of an attributes hash. So add `piece_lineup`'s fields to your list of `attr_accessors` for that model, OR try this:

```
@lineup = current_user.lineup
@lineup.piece_id = params[:piece_id]
@lineup.save
```

Also see:

> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by 'add piece_lineup's fields to your list of attr_accessors' ? thanks

Comment: also, if I do the non-mass assign suggestion you gave (the first suggestion), do I still need to do - @lineup.piece_lineups.build(:piece => piece) before the form?

Comment: @MatthewBerman Can you post your params hash so that I can be more specific.

Comment: "lineup"=>{"piece_lineups_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"piece_id"=>"1", "id"=>"4"}, "1"=>{"piece_id"=>"1"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Lineup", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"lineups", "id"=>"2"}